# TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings

Tags: python

I am running into following error ,line 158 where the error is pointing is shown below.can anyone help what is the issue and how to over come it?

```
def getGerritInfo(num):
    user = pwd.getpwuid(os.getuid())[0]
    gerritCmd = ("ssh -p 29418 review-android.quicinc.com gerrit query --format=JSON --dependencies ").split(' ')
    xargs = ['change:'+num]
    gerritPipe = Popen(gerritCmd+xargs, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE) --> line 158
    (output, error) = gerritPipe.communicate()
    if error != "":
        print error
        raise IOError, "gerrit command %s failed" % (gerritCmd)
    d = json.loads(output.split('\n')[0])
    if len(d) == 3:
        return {}
    return d
```

Error:-

```
  File "find_dependencies.py", line 437, in <module>
    main()
  File "find_dependencies.py", line 211, in main
    (dep_gerrit,depgerrit_status,depgerrit_error)=findinternaldep(internal_dep,num)
  File "find_dependencies.py", line 100, in findinternaldep
    gerrit = getGerritInfo(change)
  File "find_dependencies.py", line 158, in getGerritInfo
    gerritPipe = Popen(gerritCmd+xargs, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 679, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1249, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
TypeError: execv() arg 2 must contain only strings
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation. (Or, better, remove the irrelevant parts of your code)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
xargs = ['change:%s' % str(num)]
```

This will ensure that all the parts are strings.

Personally in your error handler I would also set `d = {}` rather than `return {}` to make sure that you only have one `return`.